# Iphone Webapp Startup Screen Delay

Tags: iphone, web-applications, splash-screen

I've made a simple iPhone webapp and I've set a startup screen and icon and everything. Here's the [link](http://www.damusic.webs.com/mobile.htm) to it.

The problem I'm having is that when I save the webapp to the homescreen, a white screen (or else a screenshot of the page I have opened on Safari) shows up first for a few seconds before the startup screen.

I've added other iPhone webapps like [JQtouch](http://jqtouch.com/preview/demos/main/#home) to my homescreen and opened them and the startup screen shows up straight away.

I'm wondering if I have something wrong in the html code???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing `<meta name="viewport" content="width=300px; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;" />` to `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0;" />` so the `width=device-width` and using commas (`,`) instead of semi-colons (`;`) except at the end of the line.

---

Do you have this in your `<head>`:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="myImage.jpg">
```

See [iOS Web App Configuration - mobile-meta-links.html](https://gist.github.com/472519) for exact specs:

```
<!-- startup image for web apps - iPad - landscape (748x1024) 
     Note: iPad landscape startup image has to be exactly 748x1024 pixels (portrait, with contents rotated).-->
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="img/ipad-landscape.png" media="screen and (min-device-width: 481px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation:landscape)" />

<!-- startup image for web apps - iPad - portrait (768x1004) -->
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="img/ipad-portrait.png" media="screen and (min-device-width: 481px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation:portrait)" />

<!-- startup image for web apps (320x460) -->
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="img/iphone.png" media="screen and (max-device-width: 320px)" />
```

---

Also read that the startup image will only show up if you use the HTML5-doctype
 `<!DOCTYPE html>`

---

From [Icons and splash screens for iOS web apps - retina displays also welcome](http://www.paulofierro.com/archives/568/):

> To insert a high-resolution splash screen into the `<head>`, but only
>   for iOS devices with a retina display running iOS5 or later:
>
> ```
> function hasRetinaDisplay() {
>   return (window.devicePixelRatio >= 2);
> }
> function isAppleDevice() {
>   return (/iphone|ipod|ipad/gi).test(navigator.platform);
> }
> function iOSNewerThan(majorVersion) {
>   if(isAppleDevice()) {
>       // Check the version
>       var pattern = /iPhone OS (.*) like Mac/;
>       var result  = navigator.userAgent.match(pattern); // Returns "iPhone OS X_Y like Mac, X_Y"
>       var version = result[1].split(''); // Returns X, Y
>       var release = version[0];
>       return (release >= majorVersion);
>   }
>   return false;
> }
>
> // When we're ready to go...
> $(document).ready(function() { 
>   if(hasRetinaDisplay() && iOSNewerThan(5)) { 
>       var highResSplash = '<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="/images/splash-iphone4.png" />'; 
>       $('head').append(highResSplash); 
>   }
> });
> ```

Comment: Yeah I have this in the head section
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="misc/startup.png">

Comment: thanks but no it's not working. I'm still getting a white screen flashing up for about 2 seconds before the startup screen. I tried to copy the code from that JQtouch webapp because that works fine when I open it up but it's not doing the same for my one .

Comment: Try changing your `<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="misc/startup.png" media="screen and (min-device-width: 200px) and (max-device-width: 320) and (orientation:portrait)" />` to just: `<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="misc/startup.png" media="screen and (max-device-width: 320px)" />` and see if that changes anything?

Comment: Another idea is to change `<meta name="viewport" content="width=300px; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;" />` to `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0;" />` so the width=device-width and using commas (,) instead of semi-colons (;) except at the end of the line.

Comment: lovely, that worked perfectly. Thanks for all your help chown!

Comment: My pleasure.  Glad you were able to get it fixed!